# Documentation to create custom content type and display it in theme in Orchard Core CMS

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, .net-5, orchardcore

I have created a content type named "Button" in Orchard Core CMS using the admin. But I am now stuck. I am not sure how to display the content type "button" in my theme. I cannot find the documentation anywhere. So I instead created a "Button.liquid" file in my views folder of my theme project. In the liquid file I have the following:

`<button>{{ Model.ContentItem.Content.TitlePart.Title }}</button>`

In my "Layout.liquid" file, I have the following:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  {% shape "button" %}
</div>
```

The idea is to have a button with some text appear in my theme. But this is what I have:[The current state of my navbar with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y25n.png)

The text does not appear. Please help. I am new to Orchard Core CMS. I just need to know how to render/display custom content types in my theme.